# tawk.to chat widget not working with django?

Tags: django, tawk.to

I am trying to add tawk.to chat widget to my django site. I used the Django-tawkto package from https://pypi.org/project/django-tawkto/. But still, it's not showing the widget on the page.
Here is the output of my page:
[My Django template for where I want to use tawk.to chat widget](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zwd2E.jpg)

I did check the page source and I can see the tawk.to script over there. But it's not working. I don't know why?

[page source for above Django template](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fgGrP.jpg)

Please help me out here.
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was not with the code. It's because I was running it on
the local machine. Tawk.to Script doesn't work on the local machine.
It works fine when you upload it on the server.

Answer (score 0):

I talked with the tawk.to support agent and he gave me a solution.

Add the below meta tag and then place the Django tawk.to tag in the head section. Both tags should be inside the head section.

```
<meta name="referrer" content="no-referrer-when-downgrade">
{% tawkto_script %}
```

if the above code doesn't work, replace the tag with the following. use your correct widget id.

```
{% tawkto_script widget_id='somewidgetid' %}
```

Answer (score 0):

For me, the solution was to add:

```
SECURE_REFERRER_POLICY = "strict-origin-when-cross-origin"
```

To `settings.py`.

You should read [the docs for this setting carefully](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/middleware/#referrer-policy) to decide whether it's an acceptable security change for your site.

Answer (score 0):

For those using the tawk to script without installing any packages:

Just add the meta tag inside the `<head> </head>`:

> `<meta name="referrer" content="no-referrer-when-downgrade">`

and paste the tawk.to script before the `</body>` tag.

This works smooth.